# Why won't table sit inside another table?

Tags: html

[image]

What I'm trying to do is position a table inside another table in order to have a border inside another larger gold border but this is the result I'm getting as illustrated in image.

(This is for HTML email)

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#001C36" align="center" class="deviceWidth" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; mso-table-lspace:0; mso-table-rspace:0;width:620px; border: 2px solid #B09969; padding:30px; box-sizing: border-box; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"> 

    <table style="border: 2px solid #B09969; width: 500px">
        CONTENT
    </table>
</table>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution or alternate method?

Comment: You cannot nest a table inside a table directly. You need to Add td and tr tags and then nest the table inside the td tag.

Comment: Even if there is no content inside tr and td tags?

Comment: The answer is yes, perfect! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `table` inside of `td` and handling with border you can use `border-collapse` [Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp)

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>I am the outer table</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>I am within the table</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```